# How can I install a third party MSI using a custom action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Visual FoxPro installer (exe) that I want to launch using a WiX custom action. However, I think the VFP installer is a wrapper for an MSI as I'm getting "Error 1500" which seems to denote I'm trying to run two installers at the same time.

How can I bootstrap this third party MSI from my own MSI?

I'm currently launching the VFP installer in InstallExecuteSequence. I tried to run it in InstallUiSequence, but I'm calling my own installer from a ShellExec, so it doesn't run the InstallUiSequence.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically infeasible with the current version of MSI. Installing your additional MSI via a bootstrapper is the recommended way.

Please see my answer to a related question here: [Wix and .NET Framework (prerequisites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/wix-and-net-framework-pre-requisites)

Comment: It is technically infeasible because the actual file installation and system changes done in an MSI is performed as a database-style transaction that is supposed to be possible to roll back if it fails. This feature is not possible if two MSI files are installing at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't and it would be a bad idea if you try to "work around" it.  If you really need this kind of functionality, use something like [NISI](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to call the 3rd-party MSI and then call yours.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened an MSI with Orca and saved it as a MSM (Merge Module) and added it to a Visual Studio setup project (not WiX sadly) before and it worked.

I'm pretty sure Orca comes with Visual Studio, but Google should give you good results to download it.

Give it a go in adding a MSM to your WiX project, and let us know what happens.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach. Upon conversion to MSM some information is bound to be lost, and this could cause problems for later updates or changes.