# Adding custom links in action dialogs

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm new to WIX and using 3.0.
   Can we display a link while displaying a dialog? basically i am stopping the installation when a framework version is missing. Requirement is to direct the user to some resource, below is what i did:

```
   <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK10"/>
    <Condition Message="Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 is missing. To download please visit **$(var.FrameworkDownload)**">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK10]]>
    </Condition>
```

Though it will display the url, obviously user can't click it or copy it? What should i do make it click-able?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by Windows Installer. A solution is to use a prerequisite instead of a launch condition: [Wix and .NET Framework (prerequisites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/wix-and-net-framework-prerequisites)

Answer (score 3):

There's actually [*Hyperlink* control type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSI. It does what you want, but it's not supported in Windows Installer 4.5 and earlier; it is supported as of version 5.0 which ships with Windows 7. (See [Released Versions of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371185.aspx) for reference.)

You can conditionally display the text using Hyperlink control, if you're running in Windows Installer 5.0 and above; or if you're in an earlier version, display text description with a regular Button control. When user clicks the button, it opens the URL you provided (in the user's default browser).