# Unable to install dotnet 4.8 on my Virtual Box using Wix Toolset

Tags: xml, windows-installer, wix3

i have build a msi which will install dotnet 4.8 using wix toolset but during installation it is giving an error that some other installation is running so that why it is unable to install it if I try to retry to it fails at the end i have to press cancel it the installation ends so please help me how to resolve this issue

**Here is how my code looks like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
    
    <Product Id="48CAD6F2-CA57-401E-AE5A-EEE8665F9750" Name="dotNetInstallationUsingWix" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Naveen Ltd" UpgradeCode="0dabc91d-b2a0-4dd2-9ceb-cde6716edef7">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        
        <MediaTemplate  EmbedCab="yes"/>
        
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        
        <Property Id="NETFRAMEWORK48INSTALLED">
            <RegistrySearch Id="DotNetFX48Installed" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Name="Release" Type="raw" />
        </Property>
        
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="dotNetInstallationUsingWix" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
        </Feature>
    
        <CustomAction 
              Id="DotNetFX48Install" 
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe&quot;/q /norestart" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Impersonate="no"
              Return="ignore"
              />
enter image description here            
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="DotNetFX48Install" After="InstallFiles">
              NOT Installed
          </Custom>
        <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    
    </Product>
        
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="Foldername" Name="dotNetInstallationUsingWix">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Softwares" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
    
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
              <Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="C2E4D2D1-ECBE-4E06-A582-E4DDC0B74191">
                <File Id="abc" Source="ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
              </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>


</Wix>
```

**and the error I am getting during installation are**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJgPl.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJAYg.jpg)

please suggest me some changes so that it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wix and .NET Framework (prerequisites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/wix-and-net-framework-prerequisites)

Comment: no this doesn't solve my problem my problem is i am facing error during installation and link u gived is for using BURN approach i want to do this using Setup project

Comment: Are you using Wix 4?  Why V4 and not V4.8? Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"  maybe try 4.72 or Core.  See following for different versions : Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install .NET from another MSI package; only one installation is allowed at a time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes